# Js window.print

Tags: html, css, javascript

js window.print есть функция, в разных браузерах по разному работает. В данный момент, я имею массив, перебором которого я генерирую сию печать, но каждый элемент массива должен распологаться строго на одном листе, для Chrome, я просто методом проб и ошибок в css подцепил высоту каждого элемента, спокойно сев, решил проверить в других браузерах, меня оно не очень приятно удивило. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте решить проблемы с помощью media queries в CSS.

```
@media print{
   .yourDivOrP{/*тут стиль для вашего елемента, который будет применяться ТОЛЬКО при печати*/}
}
```

Comment: Понимаете, есть, допустим массив данных:

 1 => (имя, фамилия, текст)
 2 => (имя, фамилия, текст)

Мне нужно чтобы каждый элемент массива был на отдельном листе при распечатке, а не сползал на другой. В данный момент я, с помощью CSS сделал фиксированную длину, и при распечатких в браузере хроме, все нормально, а в остальных каша.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9bTWERH5

Принтера нет, проверить не могу, но попробовать, думаю, стОит

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает.